# Abrir uma activity com o onMarkerClick

Tags: java, android

eu quero abrir uma nova activity quando clicar no marker, porém eu clico e não está abrindo, eu fiz mais ou menos assim:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick (final Marker marker){
    if (marker.equals("Ponto A")){
        Intent i = new Intent(Mapa.this, Tela1.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }else if (marker.equals("Ponto B")){
        Intent i = new Intent(Mapa.this, Tela2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Porém ainda não está abrindo, podem me ajudar??

eu fiz isso

```
@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
        if (marker.getTitle().equals(Log.d("onMarkerClick","Ponto A"))) {
            Intent i= new Intent(Maps.this, Tela1.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }else if (marker.getTitle().equals(Log.d("onMarkerClick","Ponto B"))) {
            Intent i= new Intent(Maps.this, Tela2.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Não pegou assim, o que faço?

Comment: Se você não colocar nenhum if, ele abre uma activity?

Comment: mas se eu não colocasse nenhum if, qual marker ele iria ler?

Comment: Qualquer marker, porém isso é bom para testar para ver se está chegando nessa parte do código, assim poderemos verificar se o erro está nos ifs, ou em outar parte

Comment: sim, é mesmo, irei tirar os ifs e por direto, cara valeu!!!!

Comment: Tirei os ifs e não funcionou também...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguinte, primeiramente estás a utilizar de maneira errônea o Log.d

Ele é utilizado para imprimir no logcat alguma informação para você verificar, e não como uma função que lhe dara um retorno.

Porém sobre o problema, vou explicar basicamente todo o caminho aqui, de maneira simples digamos (pode ser que alguém saiba explicar de maneira mais simples, mas é como conseguirei explicar no momento).

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapa_fragment);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        // Cria o marker do ponto A e seta no mapa
        MarkerOptions markerA = new MarkerOptions();
        markerA.position(new LatLng(-10.0,-10.0));
        markerA.title("Ponto A");
        markerA.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker());
        googleMap.addMarker(markerA);
        // Cria o marker do ponto B e seta no mapa
        MarkerOptions markerB = new MarkerOptions();
        markerB.position(new LatLng(10.0,10.0));
        markerB.title("Ponto B");
        markerB.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker());
        googleMap.addMarker(markerB);

        // Listener para quando clicar no mapa
        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                if(marker.getTitle().equals("Ponto A")){
                    // ABRE ACTIVITY PONTO A
                }else if(marker.getTitle().equals("Ponto B")){
                    // ABRE ACTIVITY PONTO B
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Nesse código eu chamo a função de pegar o mapa assincronamente, para que assim eu possa trabalhar com o mapa e crio um callback para quando o mapa estiver pronto.

Quando o mapa estiver pronto, eu crio 2 markers, e insiro eles no mapa, e após inseridos eu seto e crio um listener, que ao clicar em um marker, ele vai passar receber tratamento ali.

nele eu verifico se o title do marker é igual ao que setei anteriormente, e assim abro a Activity

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente!!!

Comment: O exemplo foi feito assim para ser fácil de entender, caso queira trabalhar com o maps depois, melhor guardar a classe do googlemaps em uma variavel da classe mesmo.

Fico feliz em te-lo ajudado :)

Comment: sim, sim, eu fiz isso.. só era essa duvida que eu tinha a respeito de abrir uma activity pois me compliquei um pouco. Mas cara muito obrigado mesmo e valeu pela paciência. Você é demais !

Answer (score 0):

Suponho que "Ponto A" e "Ponto B" sejam títulos das marcas.
Se assim for deve usar o método [getTitle()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#getTitle()) antes de fazer a verificação.

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick (final Marker marker){
    if (marker.getTitle().equals("Ponto A")){
        Intent i = new Intent(Mapa.this, Tela1.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Ponto B")){
        Intent i = new Intent(Mapa.this, Tela2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Cara, mesmo assim ainda não ta pegando, será que tenho que por o log?

Comment: Coloque um *"log"* antes do primeiro `if` e mais um a seguir a cada `if` para indicar por onde passa a execução após clicar na marca.

Comment: pode exemplificar?

Comment: Use 3 `Log.d("onMarkerClick", "texto");`. Substitua `"texto"` por `"antes do if"` no primeiro,  `"if Ponto A"` no segundo e `"if Ponto B"` no terceiro.

Comment: eu escrevi de novo com o Log mas não pegou

Comment: Veja [aqui](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html) como utilizar o *logcat* para "debugar" a aplicação.

Comment: eu fiz o código daquele jeito, tem algo errado?

Comment: Se você nem sabe como utilizar o *logcat* fica difícil ajudá-lo. Se a minha resposta não resolveu o problema não deve marcá-la como correcta(desmarque o V). Entretanto leia o conteúdo do link que indiquei.

Comment: Certo, muito obrigado e perdoe-me por minha ignorância. abraços!!